# avrdude on my jenkins-node: select from multiple atmelice_isp

Tags: avrdude

I am building a ci-node that should upload code to multiple targets that are connected to the same node. for this I have multiple hardware, each connected to its own atmelice and I want to control them with avrdude.exe

I know avrdude has the -P option to select a specific programmer but I have problems finding some unique id to only connect to one specific programmer where both programmers are of the same type.

Does anyone know how this can be supported with software?

Edit: upon further research I found out that the command

`avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p -P usb:xxx -v`

will give me further information which is

```
avrdude.exe: Version 6.99
             Copyright (c) Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
             Copyright (c) Joerg Wunsch

             System wide configuration file is "C:/AVRDUDE/avrdude.conf"

             Using Port                    : usb:xxx
             Using Programmer              : atmelice_isp
avrdude.exe: usbhid_open(): Found Atmel-ICE CMSIS-DAP, serno: J41800051747
avrdude.exe: usbhid_open(): Found Atmel-ICE CMSIS-DAP, serno: J42700051822
avrdude.exe: usbhid_open(): No matching device found
avrdude.exe: jtag3_open_common(): Did not find any device matching VID 0x03eb and PID list: 0x2141
avrdude.exe: opening programmer "atmelice_isp" on port "usb:xxx" failed
```

But now there is still no way to differentiate between the two or is there a way I can connect per serno?

Answer (score 1):

the documentation actually explains how this connection scheme can be done:

https://avrdude.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2-Command_Line_Options.html

> For the JTAG ICE mkII, if AVRDUDE has been built with libusb support, port may >alternatively be specified as usb`[:`serialno].

In my case

```
avrdude -c atmelice_isp -p m644 -P usb:J41800051747 -v
```

did the trick and I now can connect and select different programmers.